# how to provide authentication and authorization in application

Tags: sql, asp.net-4.0

I m creating an application in which i have three roles.
(a) Admin
(b) Manager
(c) Supervisor
What i want is when user enter details on lo-gin page first system check whether user is  whether its a valid user or not and then what kind of access he have. i think window authentication is good for this purpose now i want from you guys to tell how to should i go on this and can any one provide me a good article for it with example. 
as i have create all my pages but i don't know how to communicate with database for it.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [**Membership Providers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as these provide functionality for user authentication, and also at [**Role Providers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478950.aspx) that can provide functionality for managing user roles.

If you have any specific questions about how to go about implementing them, then please ask further questions here on stackoverflow.